# I have trouble installing the django-socialregistration app!

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django amateur, and have problems getting django-registration to work. I followed the installation instructions on their [website](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration), but for someone like me these instructions are not 100% clear as to what I should be doing. Here is what I've done:

1. I installed the oauth2 and python-openid packages using pip. I then copied the facebook.py file from the facebook-python-sdk package to my main django app directory. (As I write this, I'm wondering whether this file should be copied to the socialregistration app directory? Does it make a difference?)
2. I copied the socialregistration directory to my django project's directory.
3. I added socialresgitration to my INSTALLED_APPS setting.
4. To add socialregistration.urls to my urls.py file, I added the following line (not sure if this is correct, since the instructions don't give details):
   (r'^social/', include('socialregistration.urls')),
5. I added the facebook API key and secret key to my settings
6. I added socialregistration.auth.FacebookAuth to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.
7. I added socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.
8. Finally I added the three facebook tags they give in the instructions to one of my templates.
9. When I then load my website, I get the folllowing error:
   Caught AttributeError while rendering: Please add the `django.core.context_processors.request` context processors to your settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS set

So, what can I do? I thought installation would be quite simple, but apparently this is not the case. ANY help would be appreciated!

Oh, BTW, I'm using Django 1.2.1 and Python 2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: "2. I copied the socialregistration directory to my django project's directory." I don't think that's necessary. The installation folder should be included on your PYTHON_PATH, but not copied into your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. When my view renders the template, it needs to pass the RequestContext to the template.

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html', my_data_dictionary, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Source: http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/

Comment: It is, however, still necessary to add the context processorbove to the settings.

Answer (score 3):

> Please add the `django.core.context_processors.request` context processors to your settings.

Have you done that?

You'll need to change [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) to include `django.core.context_processors.request`.

Comment: I tried that, but the same error still persists. I dug into the source code of the socialregistration app, and this is the part that is causing the error:

    if not 'request' in context:
        raise AttributeError, 'Please add the ``django.core.context_processors.request`` context processors to your settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS set'.

I added the context processor to my main settings.py file. I assume this is the way to do it? Not sure what else it could be... :(

Comment: @Helmut - post the full `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)

Comment: This worked for me, in combination with Helmut's answer: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.core.context_processors.debug', 'django.core.context_processors.i18n', 'django.core.context_processors.media', 'django.core.context_processors.static', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 'django.core.context_processors.request',)